# access SourceMaps coffee

Tags: coffeescript, source-maps

I want to implement my own formatting for exception stack trace and I'm aware of `Error.prepareStackTrace` that works like a charm.

Problems come when I'm using coffee-script by running programs via `coffee`, without saving intermediate *.js results and their source-map files. I want to show correct line numbers from .coffee file not from compiled .js

Is it possible to access coffee-script's internal runtime sourceMaps (or obtain same values) for files being dynamically loaded at runtime via require? I know there is local variable `sourceMaps = {}` inside `coffee-script.coffee` that is used by coffee-script compiler itself, but it is not accessible outside the module closure.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the stacktrace that I get when I run `simplenested.coffee` which contains a `require 'simpleerror.coffee'`.  At least in `1.6.3`, sourceMaps for both files are used.  In between are lines for `loadFile`.  If either file is compiled beforehand, the relevant frame lines will reference the Javascript code.

```
2011:~/myjs$ coffee simplenested.coffee 
ReferenceError: x is not defined
  at foo (/.../simpleerror.coffee:4:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/.../simpleerror.coffee:7:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/.../simpleerror.coffee:2:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.loadFile (/.../coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:182:19)
  at Module.load (/.../coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:211:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/.../simplenested.coffee:2:8)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/.../simplenested.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

`simplenest.coffee`

```
require 'coffee-script'
nested=require './simpleerror'
```

`simpleerror.coffee`

```
foo = () ->
  y = 'testing'
  y = x # expect ReferenceError
  return y

foo()
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it will not help since I'm not compiling coffee into js to load and run it. I'm trying to access **current** source map of the coffee-script being run from the same coffee-script (maybe through several `require` that may be dynamically evaluated). Thanks anyway

Comment: With the current `coffeescript`, it you are indeed compiling on the fly, `prepareStackTrace` does use the appropriate `sourceMap`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the sourceMap via require "source-map".

And then you should get the filePath, line and column info in the stackTrace to convert.

Kevin has written the coffeestack library.

```
npm install coffeestack
```

Usage:

```
{convertStackTrace} = require 'coffeestack'

try
  throw new Error('this is an error')
catch error
  console.error(convertStackTrace(error.stack))
```

More detail see the [CoffeeStack](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/coffeestack) package.